# BigQuery doesn't convert some string values to date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My table has its dates in string format. I'm trying to transform them to date, but BQ is not accepting some values and I can't find the reason.

What I've tried:

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', CLIENTE.dtnasc)

PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', cast( CLIENTE.dtnasc as string))

CAST(CLIENTE.dtnasc AS DATE)
```

Error example (it's not only this value):

```
Failed to parse input string "1991-02-11 00:00:00"
```

How the date is without transfomartion:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00 (string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '1991-02-11 00:00:00')

SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', CLIENTE.dtnasc)
FROM mytable
```

Comment: It works when I try this, but I am not sure how to use it with my table.

Comment: added another example

Answer (score 1):

Consider below option (the simplest I can think of, having that your string column matches already format of timestamp - 2000-01-01 00:00:00 (string))

```
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP(CLIENTE.dtnasc))
```